# Let $V=Sp(v_1,v_2)$ and $W=Sp(v_3,v_4)$. Show that $V\oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1=(1,3,1,1), v_2=(-1,-3,1,2), v_3=(1,2,2,1), v_4=(2,2,1,1)$ and further let $V=Sp(v_1,v_2), W=Sp(v_3,v_4)$ be subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$. Prove $V+W$, to be a direct sum.

I was prepping for my Linear Algebra 2 final and got stuck on this fairly elementary problem realising that I've never proved a sum to direct, only the opposite.

Using the definition of direct sum, I couldn't immediately see how $V\cap W=\{0\}$. Then I started to wonder, is it sufficient to show that $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ is the basis of $V+W$?

One could easily see that since $V+W$ is defined as $V+W=\{v+w\in V+W:v\in V, w\in W\}$, then $V+W=Sp(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$. Further showing the span to be linearly independent is fairly straightforward.

I can't see how this wouldn't imply that $V\oplus W$, since if  $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ is linearly independent, the vector's can not be expressed as each other's linear combinations. Doesn't this imply that $V\cap W=\{0\}$, when subspaces $V$ and $W$ are spanned by these vectors?

I'd be happy if someone would be able to provide a counterexample to disprove my thinking and guide me towards a proper solution, or verify that I'm right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , it is sufficient to show that given four vectors are linearly independent.

Reason:
Let, if possible ,there is a non zero vector x which is contained in V & W.

x=c1v1+c2v2
for some scalers c1 & c2 coming from F( field).

Similarly,
x= d1v3+d2v4
for some scalers d1& d2.

Then, c1v1+ c2v2= d1v3+d2v4

It implies four vectors are linearly dependent.

Hence, it is enough to show four vectors are Linearly independent & they forms basis of V+W.

Comment: Thanks @SwapnajitDas, this was really helpful. All the best from Helsinki, Finland!

Comment: Welcome from India